# How to populate a dropdown input box dynamically

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am building an app that will be driven by a series of url calls. The first step is to display an empty input box, or select box. when the user enters a character, that character is inserted as a parameter into a URL and a list is returned to populate the dropdown.

This seemed straight forward, create a  box, wait for 'keyup' event, get the list, and populate the datalist. Then wait for user to select from the list or hit another key and then continue autocompleting or move to the next step in the process.

I have hit numerous problems that tell me that I do not really understand how to do this. Does some have a good example or explanation of how to do this?

I'm using javascript and D3 along with some other incidental code.

I have had no real problem creating the box, getting the first character typed, calling the URL, or getting back the list. When I try to populate the list only part of the list appear before the page locks up and become unresponsive.

Nothing fancy in the code, but it is in the `options.enter()` the process stops.

```
 d3.select( 'input box' ).attr( 'value', null );
 let options = d3.select( 'datalist' ).selectAll( 'option' ).data( <sorted array>) );
 options.exit().remove();
 options.enter().append( 'option' ).each( function(d){this.value = d });
 d3.select( '#VAWfund_id' ).on('select',fundIdChanged);
```

Some of the problems are:

1. when I first click on the box a list appears, I do not know where it comes from, but it is consistent and related to my environment.
2. the process fails and kill the web page.
3. I am not sure how to get differentiate between typing characters and selecting a options which will start the next step in the process.